# Apache not letting laravel handle all the routes

Tags: php, laravel

I have deployed a laravel app on digital ocean droplet with apache server.

project contains all laravel files.

project/public/        <--- this route works fine. 
project/public/login   <--- leads to default 404 page of apache.

that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIYKb.png)

I think what really happening is apache looks for /login directory and since it does not exist. It throws 404 without letting laravel handler the request.

How can I disable default 404 pages so that laravel is able to access request and handle it?

Comment: Check if you can access to `project/public/index.php/login`. If that is true, enable mod rewrite in apache.

Comment: @Tpojka Thanks a lot man, it worked like a charm

Comment: You are welcome. Just one thing: if your virtualhost setup is not done well it could be extremely dangerous. Check can you access to `project/public/.env` through browser.